# How to make one-time animation?

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

I just wonder, how to make one time animation. I have a lot of animations, but they, unfortunately, are repeating in the loop, and that's not what I wanted. Here's some code fragments:

```
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    TextureRegion currentFrame = activeAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    setDrawable(new TextureRegionDrawable(currentFrame));
}

RUNNING_ANIMATION_BY_SIDE = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.333f,framesRunningBySide,Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
SHOOTING_ANIMATION = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.333f, framesShootingFront, Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL);
STEADY_ANIMATION = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.230f, framesStandingFront, Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_RANDOM);
DYING_ANIMATION = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.230f, framesDyingFront,Animation.PlayMode.NORMAL);

setActiveAnimation(STEADY_ANIMATION);
```

How to make my actor to play animation only one-time? As you see, I've set to *DYING_ANIMATION* a *PlayMode.NORMAL*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using overloaded method `getKeyFrame(float stateTime, boolean looping)` of `Animation` class.

If you pass looping `true` as second parameter, your animation playmode will convert from `PlayMode.NORMAL` to  `PlayMode.LOOP`

so use `getKeyFrame(float stateTime)` or pass `false` as second parameter but for `STEADY_ANIMATION` playmode will converted from `PlayMode.LOOP_RANDOM` to `PlayMode.LOOP`.